# PCB making at home

Tags: design

I've made many PCBs at home but still there are some mistakes. I tried ironing, drawing methods but it doesn't work very well. I use eagle CAD for design PCBs. Please help me.

Comment: See also ["How can I successfully make a PCB at home?"](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/3320/25328)

Comment: What kinds of mistakes? What is not working well?

Comment: Too many have had success to give up. Work on small changes to your techniques and keep trying! Worse case some commercial companies are too cheap to ignore; https://oshpark.com/

Comment: "Some mistakes" is too vague to allow diagnosis of problems or suggestion of corrective measures.  Perhaps attach some photos of transfer media and boards made, after each stage like printing, transferring, etching and drilling.  Also indicate what printer model and brand of media if using toner transfer, or brand of resist and description of exposure and development methods if using UV resist.

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* XXX, but I'm afraid that we prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. If you edit your question to explain what you've tried, what problems you had with each approach and what specifically you want to avoid in the future, we can re-open the question and help address those specific issues. Also, if this question is not related to Robotics, you would be better off asking in Electrical Engineering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly better method for home-made PCBs is to [mill the copper off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printed_circuit_board_milling) of a two sided PCB.  Google pcb milling for many machines and services.

Another crazy idea that will probably get more affordable in the coming years is to use a 3D printer that can extrude conductive and non-conductive materials.